# Meteor, MongoDb: Double inserting to collection on few occurences

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, meteor

I noticed this strange behaviour, when for few users only on production, it inserts every item multiple times to collection on asynchronous Meteor call. I tried multiple things, but nothing worked. I can't test on localhost, bc it never happens to me on localhost or in production.

I spent the whole night solving this, but didn't find any solution. I suppose it's caused by new Date(), but I have to call it somewhere. The production server is in Amsterdam and it seems like it happens only for users located further outside of Europe.

I found this to be similar issue, but can't really wrap my head on how to implement - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4263

Slug is what same songs are supposed to have the same.

This is the workflow, user clicks on song that triggers addNewSong function:

```
addNewSong = function (track) {

 Globals.current_track = track;

 checkIfSongAlreadySaved();
}
```

I need to check if song is already in collection, if it's ->  route to it, else create the new song and route to it.

```
checkIfSongAlreadySaved = function() {

  loadPrimaryGlobalItems();

  Meteor.call('checkIfSongAlreadySaved', Globals.current_song_item_slug, function(error, result) {
    if( result.item ) {

      Globals.current_song_item_id = result.item._id;
      Globals.current_song_item_slug = result.item.slug;

      routeToSongPage();

      if (! (result.item.download && result.item.mp3) ) {
        downloadSong();
      }
    }
    else {

      loadSecondaryGlobalItems();

      var item = {
        slug:Globals.current_song_item_slug,
        duration:Globals.current_duration,
        thumbnail:Globals.current_song_thumbnail,
        title:Globals.current_cleaned_song,
        album:Globals.current_track.album,
        artist:Globals.current_track.artists[0],
        track:Globals.current_track.name,
        date:result.date,
      }

      Globals.current_song_item_id = Songs.insert(item);

      routeToSongPage();

      downloadSong();

      recentSongItem(result.date);
    }
  });
}
```

Add recent song

```
recentSongItem = function (date) {

  Recentsongs.insert({
    slug:Globals.current_song_item_slug,
    songId:Globals.current_song_item_id,
    title:Globals.current_cleaned_song,
    duration:Globals.current_duration,
    date:date,
  });
}
```

If creating new song,

```
downloadSong = function() {

  Meteor.call('findSong', Globals.current_song, function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result) {
        Globals.current_song_mp3 = true;
        updateSongItemDownload(result.itemDetails);
    }
    else {
      alert('not found')
    }
  });
}
```

and update song, to add download and mp3 values.

```
updateSongItemDownload = function(link) {

  Songs.update({
    _id: Globals.current_song_item_id
  },
  {
    $set: {
      download: link,
      mp3: Globals.current_song_mp3,
    }
  });
}
```

Server methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
  checkIfSongAlreadySaved: function(slug) {
    return {item: Songs.findOne({slug:slug}), date: new Date()};
  },
  findSong:function(song) {

    ServerGlobals.current_song = song;

    var result = searchSite();

    return result;
  },
});
```

EDIT:

This is my subscription, just in case it might be causing the problem:

```
Template.songPage.onCreated(function() {
  Session.set('processing', true);
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
    var id = Router.current().params.id;
    self.subscribe('singleSong', id);
    var item = Songs.findOne({_id: id});
    if (item) {
        if (item.download) {
            createSong(item.download);
        }
        else if( item.download === false ) {
            console.log('item not found');
        }
        Session.set('loader', false);
        Session.set('processing', false);
      }
   });
});

Meteor.publish('singleSong', function(id) {
    check(id, String);
    return Songs.find({_id: id});
});
```

Comment: Are you saying there are multiple songs being inserted or multiple RecentSongs?

Comment: For both it seems to run one time before and one after an update. For collection Songs, it inserts two with different IDs, but the same slugs. I've experienced the similar issue with Iron Router onBeforeAction, where it reruns the function every time Collection is updated.

Comment: findSong server Method takes approximately 1-3 secs to return, also I edited my question with publish/subscription since that might be causing the problem too.

Comment: Is it possible the user can initiate addNewSong more than once say with a double click? A request travelling from further afield would have increased latency meaning two close clicks could both arrive at the server and check for existence then both return empty before the first execution inserts so they both insert? You could test this with a small wait in the checkIfSongAlreadySaved method of a few seconds before returning to replicate the increased response time...

Comment: @PhilipPryde this is really possible, let me give it a try.

Comment: okay, this was actually the issue but caused because my stupidity,  I have a similar layout as Spotify implemented- http://i.imgur.com/lpPrOJc.png. You can initiate download by clicking on the button on the left or double clicking on the row. I recently changed double click to single click, but when I was testing, I never realized when you click on the button, you also click on the row therefore call the function twice at the same time...

Comment: So no latency this is an event bubbling up instead? try `event.stopPropagation();` in your click for your download button if you want to keep them both single click, it should prevent the row click firing when the dl button is clicked

Comment: yes, thanks for helping out. Any idea, how to delete items that got inserted twice, but the ones without download field. They have the same date, same slug. I edited my question with what I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a unique index on the slug field to ensure the same slug can only exist once and the second operation to insert will fail and show up as an error in your callback which you can discard or alert user as you desire.

`db.collection.createIndex( { slug: 1 }, { unique: true } )`

You will need to clear or modify the slug name on the dups from the db before applying the index though

Comment: the problem I see with this solution is that, the actual update won't be executed, bc it'll mark the first one as unique, before function is finished.

Comment: If you catch the duplicate error in the callback for your method you could mark it for a retry against the db